# Kotlin coroutines: How to use Array channel with filter / map?

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I need to insert a buffer of 10000 elements between the various channel processors.

`produce()` provides a way to configure the buffer size:

```
produce(capacity = 10_000) {
}
```

However `map`, `filter` default to a Rendezvous channel:

```
fun <E, R> ReceiveChannel<E>.map(context: CoroutineContext = Unconfined, transform: suspend (E) -> R): ReceiveChannel<R> =
    produce(context) { // No capacity specified, defaults to 0
        consumeEach {
            send(transform(it))
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to configure this? Currently I'm constructing my own versions of these stdlib functions with a buffer, which isn't very elegant.

Comment: If you use a dispatcher other than `Unconfined`, I wonder how `map` would even work with a rendezvous channel.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik why do you think it will not work?

Comment: @qwwdfsad Later on I realized it would, but awkwardly. The sending coroutine would remain suspended until the receiving coroutine gets and processes the item.

Comment: Just to clarify: sending coroutine is `GlobalScope.produce`, not the one which sends an element to the original channel. I honestly don't see why is it awkward for hot streams

Comment: @qwwdfsad I automatically assumed that `produce` here is just a self-contained example and that the actual work would involve communicating coroutines.

Answer (score 2):

The only way is to provide your own map implementation with `capacity` parameter:

```
fun <E, R> ReceiveChannel<E>.map(context: CoroutineContext = Unconfined, capacity: Int = 0, transform: suspend (E) -> R): ReceiveChannel<R> =
    produce(context, capacity = capacity) {
        consumeEach {
            send(transform(it))
        }
    }
```

I've created a https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/841, but it won't be implemented soon. All channel operators can be potentially reworked when cold streams are introduced to make cancellation and scopes hierarchies consistent between hot and cold data sources.